# java install already in progress clean software

Tags: java, windows, installation, windows-installer

My computer turn off when i install jdk 9, and now any java program cant be install.

Error message :

> another java installation is in progress you must complete that installation before you can run this installer

I tried alredy :

- [Can't install JDK 9 because "Another Java installation is in progress"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641878/cant-install-jdk-9-because-another-java-installation-is-in-progress)
- https://www.itsmdaily.com/another-installation-already-in-progress-error/
- http://windowsreport.com/another-installation-already-progress-error-windows-10/
- https://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_1500.xml

By the way i Don't try the option to disable WindowsIntaller service, because this option in the service properties lock on "manual" and i cant change it...

Thanks for any help

Comment: Restart your pc and try again .

Comment: thank you for your response , any way i already tried this :)

Comment: Did your computer actually shut down during install? **Have you checked your system for malware?** Perhaps try to run Windows Defender in Offline Mode if you are on Windows 10. It is in the "Advanced Scanning" section and will scan during system boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As researched by the original poster, this issue turned out to be a know problem that is not related to Windows Installer. The solution is described here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184984 (essentially involving cleanup of some lock files).

---

**Original answer here**:

Before trying anything else, please try this option and let us know if it solved the problem (I haven't had any concrete problems to test it with for a while - these tools tend to get deprecated):

- [**Microsoft Fixit: unregister programs that can't be installed or uninstalled**](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall)

Several such cleanup tools have come and gone - all deprecated and unsupported as of now (<del>MsiZap.exe</del> for example).

I am not sure if your installer is Windows Installer based - since you have added that tag to your question I just assume so.

---

Please don't ever listen to advice telling you to disable the Windows Installer service. Those "hacks" can wreck your system. In fact if you have done any changes and the service won't start and you are unable to change things back, then your best options might be the "**Last Known Good Configuration**" feature (activated by pressing F8 during system boot on Windows systems before Windows 10), or "**System Restore**" (the latter may also fix your stuck Java package, but I don't like this feature - I have seen other, unrecoverable installation / uninstallation problems occur when it is used - try as a last resort - maybe if the above tool doesn't help).

---

Some links - just for reference and easy retrieval:

- [Uninstall without an MSI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334490/uninstall-without-an-msi-file/11058378#11058378).
- [Why does MSI require the original .msi file to proceed with an uninstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208530/why-does-msi-require-the-original-msi-file-to-proceed-with-an-uninstall/1189524#1189524)
- [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)

Comment: Thank u very much, troubleshooter not work, however you defiantly right about your explanation IT IS NOT PROBLEM WITH WINDOWS INSTALLER. so pathetic i tried some of the wrong solution you warning about. The solution was delete BOTH java lock files. as was here https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184984. i will like if you will add this link to your answer and i will mark your answer as a solve one.

Comment: Thanks for that report Mayan. I have updated the top of the answer with your findings. Good luck with your project, those installers look a little challenging. Are they mixing MSI installers and non-MSI installers? That could cause other problems.

Comment: its was regular jdk install. .exe

Comment: sorry is i make confusion